# simplify if statement in textboxes?

Tags: c#

Unfortunately, I do not know if the question is already asked or not, that's why I'm doing it here.
I would like to know if you can simplify it here an example:

```
if (textbox1.text == "" && textbox2.text == "" && textbox3.text == "") {
   label1.text = "Empty boxes.";
}
if (textbox1.text == "is playing" && textbox2.text == "" && textbox3.text == "") {
   label1.text = "player is playing";
}
if (textbox1.text == "" && textbox2.text == "online" && textbox3.text == "vip") {
   label1.text = "player is online and is vip";
}
```

I'm really sorry if this questions is already asked, but I dont found that.
regards.

EDIT: here is a other example

```
if (textbox1.text != "" && textbox2.text == "" && textbox3 == "")
                    label1.Text = "1 are not empty"
                if (textbox1.text == "" && textbox2.text != "" && textbox3 == "")
                    label1.Text = "2 are not empty"
                if (textbox1.text != "" && textbox2.text != "" && textbox3 == "")
                    label1.Text = "1 & 2 are not empty"
                if (textbox1.text == "" && textbox2.text != "" && textbox3 != "")
                    label1.Text = "2 & 3 are not empty"
                if (textbox1.text != "" && textbox2.text == "" && textbox3 != "")
                    label1.Text = "1 & 3 are not empty"
                if (textbox1.text == "" && textbox2.text == "" && textbox3 == "")
                    label1.Text = "boxes empty";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you intend to use your 3 textboxes? 
They could contain everything.

Comment: You should use `else if` .

Comment: Please let know clearly what are you trying to do ? are you trying to reduce the number of if conditions executed (if so try if else), other wise if you are minifying - to reduce the js space you could do with lot of tools out there.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Refer here [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1477569.aspx?Use+of+IF+condition+to+search+textboxes+values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the `StringBuilder` class.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Example of usage](https://forums.asp.net/t/1477569.aspx?Use+of+IF+condition+to+search+textboxes+values)

Here is a code example using StringBuilder to "simplify" your second code sample:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
if (textbox1.Text == "" && textbox2.Text == "" && textbox3.Text == "")
{
    text.Append("boxes empty");
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    text.Append(CheckTextBox(textbox1, ref count, 1));
    text.Append(CheckTextBox(textbox2, ref count, 2));
    text.Append(CheckTextBox(textbox3, ref count, 3));

    text.Append("are not empty");
} 

label1.Text = text.ToString();

public string CheckTextBox(TextBox textbox, ref int count, int boxNumber)
{
    string text = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            text += "& ";
        }
        text+=$"{boxNumber} ";
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you want to test a number of combinations of equalities.
Essentially you have a "truth table" / mapping between possible inputs and outputs.
There are a few ways you could do this; below is an example of using a dictionary to map possible inputs to possible outputs:

In your actual function put the following:

```
//put the above to use in finding what value to assign
var key = new ThreeValueKey(textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text);
label1.text = ResultMap.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : DefaultResult;
```

For this to work, you'd need to have the below class:

```
//create some way of holding your "rules".  
class ThreeValueKey {
    public string Key1 {get;set;}
    public string Key2 {get;set;}
    public string Key3 {get;set;}
}
```

...and you'd need to define your rules

```
//map each of the possible rules to the value:
static readonly IDictionary<ThreeValueKey, string> ResultMap = new Dictionary<ThreeValueKey, string>() {
    {new ThreeValueKey {Key1 = string.Empty, Key2 = string.Empty, Key3 = string.Empty}, "Empty boxes."}
    ,{new ThreeValueKey {Key1 = "is playing", Key2 = string.Empty, Key3 = string.Empty}, "player is playing"}
    ,{new ThreeValueKey {Key1 = string.Empty, Key2 = "online", Key3 = "vip"}, "player is online and is vip"}
};
//if there's no match, what should we do?  Assign a default value?
const string DefaultResult = "whatever to put if there's no match";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use :

```
label1.text = (textbox1.text=="" && textbox2.text == "" && textboxt3.text=="") ? "Empty Boxes" : "Player is" + textbox1.text + textbox2.text + textbox3.text;
```

With some formatting, you can give words "and" or "&", etc

Comment: OP's code doesn't do anything if i one textbox has for example `adadsd`.
In your code you add that to the label.